# Background Color not working with display contents

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, react-bootstrap

I am trying to add `border` and `background-color` to my table but it's not getting applied.

CSS of my table :-

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
}
    
table thead,
table tbody,
table tr {
  display: contents;
}
```

CSS trying to apply which is not working

```
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { 
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) { 
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Please suggest me a way out, because I need to apply the `background-color`.
I have also tried applying.

```
tbody tr {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

This is also not working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us the html of the table

Comment: `display: contents` prevents the `wrapper` from generating any box, so its `background, border and padding` do not render.
only way I see is using some other `display` value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to select `td` :

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  overflow: auto;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) > td{ 
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) > td{ 
  border: solid 1px #e2e2e2;
  background-color: blue;
}
table thead,
table tbody,
table tr {
  display: contents;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header</th>
      <th>header</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1st row</td>
      <td>1st row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2nd row</td>
      <td>2nd row</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't remove `display:contents` as it holds the elements of the table together. If we use `display:grid` as I require the table to be a grid